# Use CSS Framework in every Vue Component with own variables

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, bulma

I'm fairly new to the world of `VueJS` and `Webpack` so I need some help.

I've installed `VueJS` and `Webpack` via the console with the command

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

and after this I've installed the [bulma CSS Framework](http://bulma.io) in this directory. with

```
npm install bulma
```

I've override some `bulma` variables in a **variables.scss**. If I import both files in the style section of my **App.vue** everything works fine.

My **App.vue** looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <top-navigation/>
    <div class="has-text-centered">
      <img src="./assets/logo.png">
      <p>Test</p>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import TopNavigation from './components/shared/TopNavigation.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      'top-navigation': TopNavigation
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import 'assets/scss/_variables.scss';
  @import '~bulma';

</style>
```

My **TopNavigation.vue** looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="blue-bg">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title">Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'hello vue'
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .blue-bg {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: $blue;
  }
</style>
```

But I get an error:

> error  in ./src/components/shared/TopNavigation.vue
>
> Module build failed:
>       background-color: $blue;
>         Undefined variable: "$blue".

---

I've searched a while and tried to import the files directly in my `webpack` **utils.js** file like this:

```
scss: generateLoaders(['css', 'sass?data=@import "./src/assets/scss/_variables.scss";@import "~bulma";']),
```

Now I don't get an error and in my `TopNavigation` is using the right blue color. But now the `bulma-variable` don't get override.

I hope you guys understand my problem and someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use scss, since bulma uses sass. Just change your **TopNavigation.vue** style to:

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
  @import '~bulma/sass/utilities/variables.sass'
  .blue-bg
    height: 80px;
    background-color: $blue;
</style>
```

And I think this should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

If you are new just like me , its better not to get overwhelmed by Webpack and stuff.

What I have done for now [would be bad practice] is to download the bulma.css from the bulma website.

Using vue-cli , let it create me a template project structure [once again I ignored the webpack magic for now , template used was webpack-simple].

Added the downloaded css file to the location in the static folder of the project structure and referenced it in my App.vue

```
<style src="../static/bulma.css">
```

The focus is to learn and develop and then get into learning more advanced stuff like the build tools webpack etc.